# Limit sending of Api calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to call an external api that updates certain information per user. Now their  api limit is 5 calls per second. Now, I may get into a situation where I need to update 50000 users. According to the provider, the only way is to call the api 50000 times and update each user individually. They don't seem to have a mass update function.

As such, I want to ensure that I don't overstep the 5 requests per second limit. I was wondering what is the best approach to achieving something like this. The solutions that I came up with is to make 5 requests, make the code pause for 1 second, then go again. Or use some sort of a stopwatch where i start it, make 5 requests, check the stopwatch and wait till 1 second has passed and then repeat.

My question is, what is the best way to solve my problem? Is what I suggested a good approach or are there better ones?

Comment: I have used https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle successfully.  It has good documentation, and can filter by IP or by client key out of the box.

Comment: I am thinking a System.Timers.Timer to trigger every 0.2 seconds (AutoReset), grab a request from a queue to send.  If requests start taking > 0.2 seconds to process, its not clear what will happen from the MS docs, but I've read comments that say it runs in a thread pool and there is a limit on how many threads will be used for the timer and may not trigger at that moment it runs out of threads to use.